# How to grep the n-th substring between given delimiters?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

Let's say we have a string and its delimiter is `?`:

```
Leslie Cheung April 1 ? Elvis August 16 ? Leonard Nimoy February 27
```

I know how to `grep` the first substring between delimiters:

```
echo $above_string | grep -oP "^[^?]*"
Leslie Cheung April 1
```

How should I change the Regex in order to grep the second or third substring?

Comment: I'd use `cut` instead of `grep`: `echo ... | cut '-d?' -f2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $above_string | grep -oP "^([^?]*\?){2}\K[^?]*"
```

Change `2` to the `n - 1` value in order to obtain the nth string.

This assumes that you want the nth string *in that line*. You have n - 1 strings with no `?` ending with a literal '?' (`\?` since it's a special character in perl regex). Then with `\K` you state you are not interested in the previous contents, thus extracting just the following text until the next separator.

Comment: thanks, very good, I do not understand the part after \K  , good you explain it ?

Comment: The `[^?]*` is the same regex you used in the question: _anything not containing a ? (the separator) in a greedy way (thus running until a `?` or an end of line is found)_

Comment: so, ^([^?]*\?){2} recognizes the first two substrings that ends in a ? , \k kills them and then the third occurence is finally greped ?

Answer (score 12):

How about using cut? If you'd like to print the 2nd pattern

`echo "$above_string" | cut -f2 -d "?"`

Second column onward

`echo "$above_string" | cut -f2- -d "?"`

Answer (score 4):

Using Awk to print the second and third records separated by newlines:

```
awk -F"?" '{printf "%s\n%s\n", $2,$3}'
Elvis August 16 
Leonard Nimoy February 27
```

If you want to swap out the record, you can set it as a variable:

```
awk -v record=2 -F"?" '{print $record}'
Elvis August 16
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` you can do:

```sh
sed '/\n/P;//d;s/[^?]*/\n&\n/[num];D'
```

...where you would replace the `[num]` above with some number representing the desired occurrence.

If the numbered occurrence you specify does not exist, as is demonstrated in the following example, `sed` will simply print nothing at all.

```sh
echo ,2,3 | sed '/\n/P;//d;s/[^,]*/\n&\n/4;D'
```

Above the first match for a sequence of zero-or-more not-comma chars are the zero chars occurring before the first comma. The second is `2` and the third is `3` - there is no fourth occurrence of that pattern and so the substitution is not successful.

Note also that not every `sed` will support the `\n` newline escape in the right-hand-substitution field and you may have to replace the `n` characters in the escape string with literal newlines.

```sh
sed '/\n/P;//d;s/[^?]*/\
&\
/[num];D'
```

With your string it does:

```sh
str='> Leslie Cheung April 1 ? Elvis August 16 ? Leonard Nimoy February 27'
for o in 1 2 3
do  printf %s\\n "$str" |
    sed "/\n/P;//d;s/[^?]*/\n:$o:&\n/$o;D"
done
```

...which is just a little `for` loop which runs `sed` 3 times trying for all 3 `[^?]*` matches and prints...

```
:1:> Leslie Cheung April 1
:2: Elvis August 16
:3: Leonard Nimoy February 27
```

...or one for each value of `$o`.

You can expand on that a little to skip over `[num]` not-null occurrences like:

```sh
i= 
until [ "$((i+=1))" -gt 10 ] &&
      printf %s\\n "$str"
do    printf %s ":$i:$str?"; done |
sed '/..*\n?*/P;s///;s/[^?]*/\n&\n/7;D'
```

...which prints...

```
:3:> Leslie Cheung April 1
 Elvis August 16
 Leonard Nimoy February 27
:10:> Leslie Cheung April 1
```

It can also be *inclusive*. For example:

```sh
printf %s\\n "$str?$str" |
sed '/.*\n[^_[:alnum:]]*/P;s///
    s/[_[:alnum:]]\{1,\}/\n&\n/3;D'
```

...which prints each on a separate line every third not-null sequence of alphanumeric and `_` characters in a concatenation of two of your strings...

```
April
August
Nimoy
Leslie
1
16
February
```

Answer (score 2):

#### sed

You can use sed for this, but it is not advisable, e.g. here is a zero-based solution that uses a quantifier to select the desired field:

```
n=1
sed 's/\([^?]*? *\)\{'$n'\}//; s/?.*//' <<<"$above_string"
```

Output:

```
Elvis August 16
```